# How to divide a number of columns by one column?

Tags: r, dataframe, divide

I have the below dataset:

```
Monday Tuesday Wednesday Friday Saturday Total
2       3      4          5      6        20
3       6      7          5      1        22
```

I am doing the below:

I need to divide first row: `2/20, 3/20, 4/20, 5/20, 6/20`

And on the second row: `3/22, 6/22, 7/22, 5/22, 1/22`.

I can do this by extracting the columns but it is long and tedious, there must be an easier way.

Comment: What is your data structure? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Hi dayne, it is a data frame and I have tried the below: df[1,1] / df[1,6] for 2/20 , df[1,2] / df[1,6] for 3/20 and so on as I need to get assign a value to each calculation. do you know if there is a faster way?

Comment: You should spend some time reading this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 18):

You can simply do

```
df[,1:5] / df[,6]
```

Comment: As a note, the same syntax works whether the data structure is a matrix or data.frame.

Comment: I somehow get this error : `Error in Ops.data.frame(df[, 2:13], df[, 14]) : 
  ‘/’ only defined for equally-sized data frames` . Any suggestions why that would happen?

Comment: I will leave my comment above for the next idiot. With respect to my own comment: you need to convert to `data.frame`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `dlyr` to operate rowwise on multiple columns:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(margrittr)

df <- data.frame(
  Monday=c(2,3), 
  Tuesday=c(3,6), 
  Wednesday=c(4,7),
  Friday=c(5,5),
  Saturday=c(6,1),
  Total=c(20,22))

df %>%
  mutate(
    across(c(1:5),
           .fns = ~./Total))
```

This then returns:

```
     Monday   Tuesday Wednesday    Friday   Saturday Total
1 0.1000000 0.1500000 0.2000000 0.2500000 0.30000000    20
2 0.1363636 0.2727273 0.3181818 0.2272727 0.04545455    22
```